# How to loop properly and replace element in string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand the `replace` method. I have a string of numbers where I would like to make some adjustments. Particularly, I would categorize the numbers based on a threshold:

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    for each in x:
        if int(each) < 5:
            x = x.replace(each, "0")
        else:
            x = x.replace(each, "1")
    return x
```

In use:

```
>>> makeAdjustment("800857237867") == "100111001111" 
True
>>> makeAdjustment("15889923") == "01111100" 
True
>>> makeAdjustment("14963896") == "00110111" 
True
```

However, if the sequence of numbers gets larger the string is converted to zero:

```
>>> makeAdjustment("366058562030849490134388085")      
'000000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: Think about it - after you've replaced all numbers above five with one, **all numbers are below five**.

Comment: The `replace` method returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. So, eventually everything is becoming zero.

Comment: each is a number right? and replace replaces all numbers, not just the number at that position. Do you want it positional?

Comment: It may help to understand, if you print `x` for each step.

Comment: @m0nhawk what's with the antipathy for [tag:Python-3.x]? You even remove it from questions that specifically mention that version. Seems like a waste of time, given that you aren't fixing other obvious problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here isn't that the string is larger, it's that instances of `'1'` or `'0'` shouldn't be replaced. When you encounter a `'1'` later on in the string (as in your last case) you'll replace all previous instances of `'1'` with `'0'`.

One solution is to special case them:

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    for each in x:
        if int(each) in {'1', '0'}:
            continue
        if int(each) < 5:
            x = x.replace(each, "0", 1)
        else:
            x = x.replace(each, "1")
    return x
```

This is one option but it isn't the best since you're calling `replace` *for every iteration*. You can do much better by just using `join` here:

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    return "".join("1" if int(i) > 5 else "0" for i in x)
```

which is cleaner, clearer and faster:

```
# for loop 
%timeit makeAdjustment("366058562030849490343880185")
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.1 µs per loop
# join
%timeit makeAdjustment("366058562030849490343880185")
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace each character, build a new string character by character instead of using `replace`:

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    result = []
    for each in x:
        if int(each) < 5:
            result.append("0")
        else:
            result.append("1")
    return ''.join(result)
```

or in short:

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    return ''.join("0" if int(each) < 5 else "1" for each in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing it is just to turn it into a list and go by position. It's so much easier since replace is replacing **All each characters no matter where the position**  Here we use each as an index to keep track of our location in the list

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    x = list(x)
    for each in range(len(x)+1):
        if int(x[each]) < 5:
            x[each] = '0'
        else:
            x[each] = '1'
        #Turn it back into a string instead of a list 
        x = "".join(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def makeAdjustment(x):
    splitted = [c for c in enumerate(x)]
    for each in splitted:
        if int(each[1]) < 5:
            splitted[each[0]] = "0"
        else:
            splitted[each[0]] = "1"

    return "".join(splitted)
```

EDIT: The above code splits the string and makes a list of tuple where each character in the string is accompanied by index of it. This is done using `enumerate`.

The list (`splitted`) is enumerated where `each[1]` will contain the actual character from the string whereas `each[0]` will contain the index of the actual character in the given string.

Based on the value contained in `each[1]` the value contained at `each[0]` index of the splitted is modified.

In the end, the string is joined using `"".join(splitted)`.

Comment: Could you maybe add a couple sentences explaining your solution? To many, just viewing code isn't helpful.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: I have added the explanation. Doesn't feel pythonic but gets the work done.